# Trigger for audit table

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers

I am trying to run this code to create a trigger for my audit table, but I am getting the error message:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TRG_AUDIT_EMP" when expecting one of the following: if
```

How can I fix this problem?

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_audit_emp
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON emp_mb
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_trg_action VARCHAR2(6);
BEGIN
  IF updating
  THEN
    v_trg_action := 'UPDATE';
  ELSE IF deleting
  THEN
    v_trg_action := 'DELETE';
  ELSE IF inserting
  THEN
    v_trg_action := 'INSERT';
  ELSE
    v_trg_action := 'NULL';
END IF;
  IF v_trg_action IN ('DELETE','UPDATE') THEN
   INSERT INTO emp_audit
  ( emp_id,  emp_forename,  emp_surname, username, AUDIT_USER,  AUDIT_DATE,  AUDIT_ACTION)
   VALUES
  (:OLD.emp_ID, :OLD.emp_forename, :OLD.emp_surname, :old.username, UPPER(v('APP_USER')), SYSDATE, v_trg_action);
  ELSE
   INSERT INTO emp_audit
  ( emp_id,  emp_forename,  emp_surname, username, AUDIT_USER,  AUDIT_DATE,  AUDIT_ACTION)
   VALUES
  (:NEW.emp_id, :NEW.emp_forename, :NEW.emp_surname, NEW.username, UPPER(v('APP_USER')), SYSDATE, v_trg_action);
  END IF;
END trg_audit_emp ;​
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `trg_audit_emp` after the `END`  syntax ! and also you need to END your `ELSE IF`
**Example:**

```
       create or replace TRIGGER trg_audit_emp
      AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON emp_mb
      FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
      v_trg_action VARCHAR2(6);
    BEGIN
      IF updating
      THEN
        v_trg_action := 'UPDATE';
      ELSE IF deleting
      THEN
        v_trg_action := 'DELETE';
      ELSE IF inserting
      THEN
        v_trg_action := 'INSERT';
      ELSE
        v_trg_action := 'NULL';
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END IF;
      IF v_trg_action IN ('DELETE','UPDATE') THEN
       INSERT INTO emp_audit
      ( emp_id,  emp_forename,  emp_surname, username, AUDIT_USER,  AUDIT_DATE,  AUDIT_ACTION)
       VALUES
      (:OLD.emp_ID, :OLD.emp_forename, :OLD.emp_surname, :old.username, UPPER(v('APP_USER')), SYSDATE, v_trg_action);
      ELSE
       INSERT INTO emp_audit
      ( emp_id,  emp_forename,  emp_surname, username, AUDIT_USER,  AUDIT_DATE,  AUDIT_ACTION)
       VALUES
      (:NEW.emp_id, :NEW.emp_forename, :NEW.emp_surname, NEW.username, UPPER(v('APP_USER')), SYSDATE, v_trg_action);
      END IF;
    END;
/
```

Comment: Cheers for response but i got this error. Error at line 24: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: what is you 24 line ?

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL the syntax for an IF statement is

```
IF condition THEN
  statement
ELSIF condition THEN
  statement
ELSE
  statement
END;
```

You had `ELSE IF` instead of `ELSIF`, and then too many `END IF`s.

Try this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_audit_emp
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON emp_mb
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_trg_action VARCHAR2(6);
BEGIN
  IF updating THEN
    v_trg_action := 'UPDATE';
  ELSIF deleting THEN
    v_trg_action := 'DELETE';
  ELSIF inserting THEN
    v_trg_action := 'INSERT';
  ELSE
    v_trg_action := 'NULL';
  END IF;

  IF v_trg_action IN ('DELETE','UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO emp_audit (emp_id, emp_forename, emp_surname,username,
                           AUDIT_USER, AUDIT_DATE, AUDIT_ACTION)
    VALUES (:OLD.emp_ID, :OLD.emp_forename, :OLD.emp_surname, :old.username, 
            UPPER(v('APP_USER')), SYSDATE, v_trg_action);
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO emp_audit (emp_id,  emp_forename,  emp_surname, username,
                           AUDIT_USER,  AUDIT_DATE,  AUDIT_ACTION)
    VALUES (:NEW.emp_id, :NEW.emp_forename, :NEW.emp_surname, NEW.username, 
            UPPER(v('APP_USER')), SYSDATE, v_trg_action);
  END IF;
END trg_audit_emp;​
```

Share and enjoy.